# Move all `None` to the end of a list (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list like

```
[None, None, 90, 10, None, 34, None, 108]
```

What's an easy way to move all `None`s to the end without disturbing the order of the other elements? So, you'd get something like

```
[90, 10, 34, 108, None, None, None, None]
```

---

One possible solution is using `filter` with `None` and then just appending `None`s at the end:

```
In [890]: l2 = list(filter(None, l))

In [891]: l2 += [None] * (len(l) - len(l2))

In [892]: l2
Out[892]: [90, 10, 34, 108, None, None, None, None]
```

However,

> `filter(None, ...)` doesn't mean "filter out `None`s"; `None` is
>   special-cased to the identity predicate, so this will also filter out
>   0, False, and anything else that returns False from `__bool__`.

So, this isn't a good solution. Is there anything better?

Comment: You should be more than able to do the translation of “moving X to the beginning” to “moving Y to the end”. Also, please do not use your gold badge to reopen your own question without other’s support.

Comment: @poke It's not even the same Python version.

Comment: I don't see anything in this question or the proposed solutions that is inextricably bound to the version of Python. I'm with @poke.

Comment: And that matters why? There is nothing version specific about this at all. Some of the answers here even assume Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know `Big O` but this:

```
l2 = [x for x in l if x is not None]
l2 += [None] * l.count(None)
```

just works, and

```
l2.extend([None] * l.count(None))
```

is loved by many pythonists and

```
l2 += [None] * (len(l) - len(l2))
```

is [better](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: I would recommend changing the last line into something like `l2.extend(None for x in range(none_count)`. The generator expression would be faster and less memory intensive since you don't have to allocate a separate array.

Comment: @Zizouz212 :Done it.

Comment: `l = [x for x in l if x is not None] + [x for x in l if x is None]`

Comment: @Zizouz212: Generator expressions usually aren't faster, actually. Their benefits are memory consumption and the ability to stop them early.

Comment: @user2357112 I think it just depends on the use case. Most of my cases have always had them faster by a few seconds, but I think that has to do with allocation rather than the actual time to execute.

Comment: I preferred `l2.extend([None] * l.count(None))` to the current solution actually. But this is quite nice, (better than the sorted version).

Comment: This works, although it does two linear scans over `l` twice; that also applies to DragonBobZ's suggestion. Using a traditional `for` loop you can do it in a single scan.

Comment: Original idea iterates twice (once for filtering the list, once for counting the `None`s). Last one only iterates once and `len(list)` is constant time, so this is very efficient. Time complexity is O(n) for both though (at least ignoring the list operations).

Answer (score 8):

This *will* preserve the sorting of the list:

```
>>> l = [None, None, 90, 10, None, 34, None, 108]
>>> sorted(l, key = lambda x: x is None)
[90, 10, 34, 108, None, None, None, None]
```

because, quoting [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted):

> The built-in sorted() function is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example, sort by department, then by salary grade).

Comment: Plus1. Nice. I initially tried this but could't solve it.

Comment: _"This should preserve the sorting"_ This _will_ preserve the order of the list elements. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted): "The built-in sorted() function is guaranteed to be stable."

Comment: @Rawing Thanks, updated the post

Comment: Note that this solution is still O(n log n) though since sorting doesn’t get cheaper with a simpler key function.

Answer (score 5):

I'd build a list without Nones and pad it:

```
l2 = [x for x in l if x is not None]
l2 += [None] * (len(l) - len(l2))
```

Alternatively, there's a one-liner. I think it's theoretically O(nlogn), but I haven't observed that in practice - I think Timsort's galloping mode reduces the comparisons involved to something closer to but not quite O(n), and the data movement costs have too low a constant factor to dominate the runtime even if they're O(nlogn). In practice, the bigger disadvantage is probably that you have to think about how booleans are ordered:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x is None)
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? It works perfectly.

Comment: Also, I see I was on the right track with the padding.

Comment: Why is this O(nlogn)? I think this is just O(n), and very pythonic

Comment: `lambda`s are not pythonic.

Comment: @user2341726: `sorted` is O(nlogn) in general, and I don't think this hits any of the cases where TimSort gets to be O(n).

Comment: I'm not sure why an answer posted after this got more upvotes than this did though they both say the same thing, or the fact that 5 people attempted to answer this, but this question has no upvotes.

Comment: Experiment suggests that this may be hitting one of the O(n) cases, or perhaps the overhead of the key computation is dominating the runtime.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The version using `sorted` is faster than you might expect because TimSort is optimised for lists that contain subsequences that are already sorted.

Comment: @user2357112 but you don't need to sort, the new list is generated by the ord r of old list

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yeah, but my experiments don't have significant sorted subsequences.

Comment: @user2341726: The `sorted` version is performing a full stable sort of the key values.

Answer (score 3):

A solution to keep you up at night:

```
>>> example = [None, None, 90, 10, None, 34, None, 108]
>>> 
>>> def some(a, *b):
...     return ([*some(*b), a] if a is None else [a, *some(*b)]) if b else [a]
... 
>>> print(some(*example))
[90, 10, 34, 108, None, None, None, None]
```

**Explanation**

We pass the the data into our function using `*example` so that the elements of the list become arguments.  We then segment these arguments at function call using `(a, *b)` to place the first argument in `a` and the rest in `b`.  Recursively, if `a` is `None` then the answer is:

```
[*some(*b), a]
```

which moves `a` to the end.  Otherwise, the answer is:

```
[a, *some(*b)]
```

which keeps `a` in front and processes the rest of the list.

Finally, we have the `if b else [a]` bit which is just the base case of our recursion.

**Bake-Off**

We've enough solutions that it's time for a bake-off.  (Let me know if I've misrepresented your solution.)  We'll be summing up ten timings of a 10,000 element list in which 30% of the elements are `None`. I've eliminated zeros from the data so that everyone can play:

```
import sys
import timeit
import random

A = [random.randint(1, 1000) if random.random() > 0.3 else None for _ in range(10000)]  # ~30% None

def Rahul_comprehension(A):

    B = [x for x in A if x is not None]
    B += [None] * A.count(None)

    return B

def coldspeed_filter(A):

    B = list(filter(None, A))
    B += [None] * (len(A) - len(B))

    return B

def user2357112_comprehension(A):

    B = [x for x in A if x is not None]
    B += [None] * (len(A) - len(B))

    return B

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
def cdlane_recursion(A):

    def some(a, *b):
        return ([*some(*b), a] if a is None else [a, *some(*b)]) if b else [a]

    return some(*A)

from functools import reduce
def PaulMcG_reduce(A):

    return sum(reduce(lambda a,b: a[b is None].append(b) or a, A, ([], [])), [])

from itertools import zip_longest
def PaulMcG_zip_longest(A):

    non_nones = filter(lambda x: x is not None, A)
    return next(zip(*zip_longest(non_nones, A)))

def Massimiliano_sorted(A):

    return sorted(A, key=lambda x: x is None)

# sanity check to make sure everyone agrees on the answer
B = Rahul_comprehension(A)  # the accepted answer
assert B == coldspeed_filter(A)
assert B == user2357112_comprehension(A)
assert B == cdlane_recursion(A)
assert B == PaulMcG_reduce(A)
assert B == list(PaulMcG_zip_longest(A))
assert B == Massimiliano_sorted(A)

print("Rahul_comprehension:", format(timeit.timeit('B = Rahul_comprehension(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
print("coldspeed_filter:", format(timeit.timeit('B = coldspeed_filter(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
print("user2357112_comprehension:", format(timeit.timeit('B = user2357112_comprehension(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
print("cdlane_recursion:", format(timeit.timeit('B = cdlane_recursion(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
print("PaulMcG_reduce:", format(timeit.timeit('B = PaulMcG_reduce(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
print("PaulMcG_zip_longest:", format(timeit.timeit('B = PaulMcG_zip_longest(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
print("Massimiliano_sorted:", format(timeit.timeit('B = Massimiliano_sorted(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".2"))
```

**Sorted Typical Best Runs:** (lowest is best)

```
coldspeed (filter):          0.002
user2357112 (comprehension): 0.0041
Rahul (comprehension):       0.0061
PaulMcG (zip_longest):       0.024
PaulMcG (reduce):            0.025
Massimiliano (sorted):       0.026
cdlane (recursion):          5.8
```

Comment: Are you going to fly away on your magical unicorn or are you going to explain how this works? :p

Comment: This has the flaw of treating all falsy objects the same as None, just like cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's original `filter`.

Comment: `not a` should be `a is None` to allow for falsey non-None values (like 0).

Comment: @PaulMcG, already detected and fixed while writing the requested explanation -- thanks!

Comment: Probably better to use the ternary `x if condition else y` form than your `[false_path, true_path][condition]` form. Otherwise you call `some` recursively to build both list values and then throw away the one you don't want. Since each call then further calls recursively, this ends up being a *lot* of function calls. Although this will also serve to deobfuscate your code a bit, which may have been part of your original intent. But very clever solution!

Comment: @PaulMcG, that double evaluation bothers me too so I've unwound it to a ternary conditional and updated my explanation.  Efficiency takes all the mystery out of programming...

Comment: This looks extremely slow with all the list creation

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `itertools.zip_longest` to pad the shorter of two sequences with `None`s.  The first sequence is the non-`None` items from the original list, the second is the full original. `zip_longest` will return tuples of items from each sequence, padding with None for the shorter of the two. Then we re-zip those tuples to get back sequences, and take the first sequence, representing the filtered sequence padded with as many `None`s as needed to be as long as the original.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>>
>>> seq = [None, None, 90, 10, None, 34, None, 108]
>>>
>>> non_nones = filter(lambda x: x is not None, seq)
>>>
>>> reordered = next(zip(*zip_longest(non_nones, seq)))
>>>
>>> print(reordered)
(90, 10, 34, 108, None, None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

@cdlane's solution made me think of using `reduce`:

```
>>> seq = [None, None, 90, 10, None, 34, None, 108]
>>>
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reordered = sum(reduce(lambda a,b: (a[0], a[1]+(b,)) 
                                       if b is None else (a[0]+(b,), a[1]), 
                           seq, ((), ())), ())
>>> print(reordered)
(90, 10, 34, 108, None, None, None, None)
```

EDIT:
I couldn't sleep thinking about all those tuple additions, this is better:

```
>>>> reordered = sum(reduce(lambda a,b: a[b is None].append(b) or a, seq, ([], [])), [])
```